# How to add environment to JWT token in OAuth 2

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I am currently using JWT token as part of OAuth2 to secure my Rest APIs. The setup is done and able to access the APIs using the access tokens that are generated based on logged in user. But when my project is deployed in different environments I am able to access the Rest APIs of all the environments with a single JWT token(access token) which not recommended.

So my use case is I want to restrict Dev environment's access token to be used only in Dev, but not in QA or PROD. How this can be resolved?

Looking to add the environment to the token itself while generating but seems like OAuth is not providing any such property called environment. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the information you have provided, it seems like you are using the same Key to sign the JWT token in your Dev, QA and PROD environments. Try using different keys for signing as well as enable encryption using different keys to avoid this.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried this method and it worked.